# jquery :has check for images then apply css

Tags: jquery

If relatedProductsArea contains NO images then HIDE the div.

```
<div id="RelatedProductsArea" style="border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;"><br clear="all"><div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Finding NO images means there are no related products.

**What i have tried:**

```
$('#RelatedProductsArea').has('img').css('border', 'none');
```

Heres an example: http://jsfiddle.net/K2Cp6/

**Question:** how do i hide the div or remove the border in my jsfiddle example?

Comment: Ive answered it. I needed to use NOT rather than has.

Comment: @Blazemonger: We all started somewhere. No need to patronize.

Comment: What does that mean? You have nearly 400 rep, you know by now how to write questions that can be easily understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($('#RelatedProductsArea img').length)) {
  $('#RelatedProductsArea').hide();
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K2Cp6/4/)**

or

```
$('#RelatedProductsArea').not(':has(img)').hide();
```

**[`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not)** will filter `div` with no image.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K2Cp6/3/)**

or

```
$('#RelatedProductsArea').has(':not(img)').css('display', 'none');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K2Cp6/2/)**

#### According to edit

To hide use `.hide()` or `.css('display','none')` and to remove border use `.css('border', 'none')`. If you want both the

```
.css({
   display: 'none',
   border: 'none'
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('#RelatedProductsArea:not(:has(img))').hide()
```

You need to use the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to select elements that do not match the given selector. In this case, `#RelatedProductsArea` that does not have `img`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#RelatedProductsArea:not(:has(img))').css('border', 'none');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/K2Cp6/1/

Try adding and removing `<img />` element to `#RelatedProductsArea` to test.

> If relatedProductsArea contains NO images then HIDE the div.

Use `.hide()` instead of `.css('border', 'none')` if you wish to hide the div.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#RelatedProductsArea').find("img").length == 0)
   $('#RelatedProductsArea').css('border', 'none');
```

Answer (score -3):

solution was easy:

```
$('#RelatedProductsArea').not('img').css('border', 'none');
```

Comment: This is border not visibility

Comment: `border:none` don't hide the element. it should `display:none`. I think you're in illusion, friend.